# Want to get value from a seekbar in a button android

Tags: android

I am using a seekbar and tracking it's value and I want in my button to see if the progress is greater than 0. However with my code , it's not working. I don't know what am I doing wrong here. Thanks

```
mySeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sb1);
mySeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress6, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        myTextView.setText(" " + progress6);
    }
```

//Now in the click event of button, I want to check if the value of seekbar is greater than zero.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

String getVal = myTextView.getText().toString();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(getVal);


        if(num >= 0){

// do something

        }
```

Comment: Is your seekbar processing?

Comment: Yes it is showing the progress int as the user slides it.

Comment: Are you getting a NumberFormatException?

Comment: errors java.lang.Integer.invalidInt, java.lang.Integer.parseInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line causes trouble because of the leading space. Integer.parseInt(..) takes only Strings with just numbers (no spaces, letters etc.)

```
myTextView.setText(" " + progress6);
```

Change it to:

```
myTextView.setText("" + progress6);
```

Comment: Quick question, how can i check if seekbar hasn't been selected in the button event , I mean the value is less than 0(I have set seekbar value 0-9)

Comment: Well, AFAIK negative values are not possible with the seekbar. You can check if a seekbar is in its initial state if the SeekBar.getProgress() returns the inital value you set or "0" for the default.